Is there a list of all kMDItemContentType value's - or most common at least?
Does anyone know of such a list?  And can you generate a list from the file types on your system?
For example:

public folders - mdfind 'kMDItemContentType == public.folder'

And what about kind, as in - mdfind kind:image -name beach.  Can you get a list of possible kinds?  Is it the same as kMDItemKind?
I found what I assume is a reduced list in https://www.macworld.com/article/189962/spotlight2.html
Cheers!

Here is a comprehensive list from Apple Developer:  Spotlight Metadata Attributes

@Allan Though important that is a list of metadata attribute names, not the values associated with specific metadata attributes which what I think the OP is asking. You might like to look at my answer, and correct it (where needed) or do better!

I guess you are at the start of an exploration of file types and how they are used by the Spotlight index and by search tools. To answer your questions:
There can't be a "complete" list of kMDItemContentTypes because their structure is open ended - any developer can create a new one.
For example, Markdown format was not created by John Gruber (the owner of Daring Fireball) and the ContentType information is:
kMDItemContentType                 = "net.daringfireball.markdown"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
        "net.daringfireball.markdown",
        "public.plain-text",
        "public.text",
        "public.data",
        "public.item",
        "public.content"
kMDItemKind                        = "Markdown"

The ContentTypeTree is important because this indicates that Markdown files are public.plain-text which can be indexed by Spotlight without any additional plugins.
I don't know of a list of common types.
You ask about images. Here are a few items of the metadata associated with an iPhone photo:
kMDItemContentType                               = "public.heic"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                           = (
    "public.heic",
    "public.heif-standard",
    "public.image",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemKind                               = "HEIF Image"

I deduce from this (and metadata for other image types) that a search for mdfind kind:image is using public.image in the ContentTree to identify images.
kMDItemKind is more specific than just an image (in the above case an HEIF Image - so is not the same as kind:image.
As you have realised mdfind can use searches like kind:image where mdfind will convert the friendly term "image" into kMD... searches.
The MacWorld article you reference has list of some (I doubt it is all) of those friendly terms like "image". Note that as well as including fairly general terms like "image", it can also be more specific (e.g. "jpeg").
As with kMDItemContentType and kMDItemContentTypeTree, I am not aware of a list of kMDItemKind values.
Most importantly, your exploration will be assisted by using mdls <file path> to display all the Spotlight metadata associated with a file.

Tentatively I suggest this command to give a list of all possible values which could be in kMDItemContentType and kMDItemContentTypeTree:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep "uti:" | sort -u > uti.txt
This dumps the Launch Series database and extracts unique lines with Uniform Type Identifiers which your Mac knows about and which can be used in kMDContentType and kMDContentTypeTree searches.
Someone, please correct that last bit if it is rubbish!

Some useful references:
From Howard Oakley (who expresses things so much better than me): File types, the UTI, and even more metadata.
Also this question is relevant: Where do UTIs come from.
